# override object color on Linked Group

Tags: python, texturing, source-code

I have a linked library I am creating with a bunch of assets.  Example.  A modular house sections ie. types of roofs and so on, each section made of multiple meshes.

I need to quickly make houses and building with this modular system and then be able to edit the color ramp and/or material. I use a random node with a color ramp to make the meshes different colors. But each scene will need the colors modified without effect the original mesh in the library.

I have gotten as far as to be able to change a material color with a simple script, typing in the diffuse colors.  Which make me think as long as the material is on the object not the data it should be able to be overridden some how.  I have seen several posts around about similar issues but so far not any working solutions.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Amanda

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue that will be resolved when overrides arrive in Blender.

However, a possible solution for your problem right now could be the following:
**Drivers**.

You can add drivers to the parameters in the node tree that you want to influence. E.g. attach the Factor of a Mix node to the x-Position of an Empty.
Make sure the Empty is in the same collection that you link.

Then, when you link the collection in a new blend file, you can create a proxy of the Empty and consequently use it to change the material.

I hope this helps point you to a working solution.

Comment: oh interesting thanks! I give that a try